# Create a new annotator in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: annotations, text-processing, stanford-nlp

I need to create and add a new annotator for analysing text in Stanford CoreNLP. There are solution to add a new annotator. I can't find how to create a new annotator?

I need to create a neww annotator for Newsfeed source names in Stanford CoreNLP annotator list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [the documentation](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/new_annotator.html), you need to implement the [Annotator](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/Annotator.java) interface, with a constructor taking parameters `MyAnnotator(String, java.util.Properties)`, and then in the properties file you pass into CoreNLP, set a parameter

```
customAnnotatorClass.NAME=CLASS
```

For example:

```
customAnnotatorClass.myann=com.domain.package.MyAnnotator
```

Then, you can pass properties into the annotator by defining properties:

```
myann.myprop=myvalue
myann.otherprop=othervalue
```

These will show up in the `Properties` object passed into the constructor of the Annotator you created.

A good example of a small Annotator that can be used as a template for what a custom annotator should look like could be the [Gender annotator](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/GenderAnnotator.java).